# @Embedded &@Id questions

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I am new to Objectify and I had some doubts that is best illustrated in code

```
public class Uid {
@Id private String name; // e-mail id
    private String oauth2_token; // A token 
... // constructors/setters/getters
};

public class Message {
@Id Long msg_id;
private String message;
@Embedded private Uid uid;
... // constructors/setters/getters
};
```

1. Can the fields be **private** if I intend for them to be persisted?
2. class **Uid** has a field marked **@Id**, then **Uid** is **@Embedded** into class **Message** which has a separate **@Id** field (albeit different types. Is this permissible at all and if yes, then are there caveats/exceptions?

Thx and cheers.

Comment: Did you intend to have two @Id annotations in class Uid?  If so, that is incorrect... Only one field can hold the identity per class.

Comment: Sorry about the erroneous extra **@Id** field. U r right, I only intended for one **@Id** field in **Uid**.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes

2) No, an embedded class does not have an @Id in objectify. You should read the docs here: http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#@Embedded

Embedding actually flattens your embedded class into the same table as the enclosing object. An id in appengine is very specific, it's used to create a datastore key. It would make no sense to have an Id on a class that doesn't actually represent an entity in the datastore.

The idea of embedded objects in objectify is that you want to treat them as separate objects in the java world but for performance purposes you want to query on them. This sort of gets around the lack of joins in bigtable (for a few use cases anyway). You can query on their properties in relation to the enclosing class.

Answer (score -1):

1) Yes, private fields will be persisted. I'd recommend annotating all of your fields, with @Indexed, @NotIndexed, or @NotSaved.

2) I think that it is okay... at least, I think that it will work within Objectify, but you should definitely consider if it means what you think that it means.  Maybe you are intending to have some Uid's as normal stand-alone Entities, but some embedded within Messages?  See:
http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#@Embedded

The GAE Java/JDO docs also talk about Embedded classes.  It is a little different in JDO, but maybe it is helpful background material:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses#Embedded_Classes

Another option would be to use something like `Key<Uid>` in Message, instead, but it depends on what you are doing with it.

Comment: You're wrong on #2. And objectify has no relation to jdo at all. If you're using objectify it's helpful to forget everything you know about jdo (but learn everything you can about big table).

Comment: I think that the question was whether or not it is permissible to have an Embedded class with an \@Id field in it.  My quick test with Objectify 3.1 indicates that, yes, the embedded class can have a field marked with \@Id, although that field doesn't do anything special within the enclosing entity.  Give it a try and see.  Rick, perhaps you are correct that I shouldn't have mentioned GAE/JDO, but on the other hand I thought the Google documentation explained the purpose of it better then the Objectify docs.

Comment: You can annotate a field with anything you want, but that doesn't make it right to do so... It's wrong if you think it's going to make it part of a key, which is the purpose of the annotation.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Jeffrey, I take your point about the Key<Uid> and that is a better alternative to what I had in mind, tho' in my case, it makes more  sense to replace it with a hash of the Uid, or something that can uniquly access the Uid entity in the data store.

Comment: @pbhowmick: Actually, I think that the key might do what you are looking for... You can use a key to quickly/cheaply retrieve the particular Uid from the datastore.